# telnet to Yandex's smtp port wont work on Google Cloud Plaltform

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, telnet

I'm trying to send mail on my server which on located on vps in Google Cloud. I can telnet to gmail's SMTP both 587/465 but i can't connect via telnet to Yandex.

It's stucking on Trying ....

```
# telnet mail.yandex.ru 587
Trying 213.180.193.125...
```

I opened all ports (both tcp and udp) but still same.

Comment: Ask google support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with solution. Unfortunately Google is blocking port 25, 465 and 587 for `our sake`. Only Gmail and GSuite is supported on Google Cloud Engine.

For further information see link below;

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/